# Adding positive integer to int causes it to become negative

Tags: c#

my issue is that when I am adding only positive numbers to an integer it can sometimes become negative. I know that the numbers that are added to the integer are never positive as I have tried putting them in

```
maths.abs()
```

My code is below and i would really appreciate some help

```
int Total = 0;
int First = 0;
int Second = 10000;   
while (First <= Second)
{
    Total += 5000 + (250 * First);
    Console.WriteLine(Total);
    First++;
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: You are overflowing the integer

Comment: Sorry can you explain, is the integer value getting too big, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: What do you expect to happen if you had `int.MaxValue + 1`?  Hint: focus on the name `MaxValue`.

Comment: An `int` in C# is a 32bit integer.  Meaning it can only handle values from `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.  Step through your code, check to make sure it never attempts to assign a value to total that exceeds that

Comment: I ran this code locally.  It is definitely overflowing as soon as `First` is 4125.

Comment: In you snippet, the same happens using Int32, but does not using Int64... `Int64 Total = 0;`

Comment: Your code is actually a good example of integer overflow.

Comment: @blaze_125 do you mind posting that as an answer and I will be happy to accept :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by others, your `int` can't take that number and overflows. Using an `Int64` instead does what you want.

```
Int64 Total = 0;
int First = 0;
int Second = 10000;   
while (First <= Second)
{
    Total += 5000 + (250 * First);
    Console.WriteLine(Total);
    First++;
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: plz use the suggested alias for the struct. I.E. long

Answer (score 5):

Please read [Checked and Unchecked (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/checked-and-unchecked).  You can opt in to bounds checking on arithmetic operations.  EG:

```
int Total = 0;
int First = 0;
int Second = 10000;

while (First <= Second)
{
    checked
    {
        Total += 5000 + (250 * First);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(Total);
    First++;
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: That doesn't work System.OverflowException
  HResult=0x80131516
  Message=Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Comment: @15wshepth it worked exactly as its supposed to.  It is throwing an exception instead of just overflowing the integer.  Thats why its being `checked` to make sure you dont perform an operation that will overflow `Total`.  Instead of just silently overflowing your integer it throws an exception so you can handle it.  You likely want to figure out a new way of doing this though. There isnt anything you can do to change how much fits in a 32 bit integer, thats just math...

Comment: Oh right sorry I didn't quiet understand what you meant by your answer thanks for the clarification :D. It doesn't quiet answer the question as it doesn't solve it however thanks for helping me understand this more

Comment: @15wshepth No matter how big your shoebox is, you can only fit so many cats into it.  Your only choices are to get a bigger box, or use fewer cats.  No magic keyword will change that truth.  Your choice is: do you want an error as soon as you get a tragic cat overflow?  Or do you want to just keep adding cats to the box while they hop out and plot revenge against you?

Comment: @maccettura I concede my analogy has a few flaws.

Comment: @Amy I was trying to make a Schrodingers cat joke but I just gave up haha

Answer (score 1):

2,147,483,647 is the limit of the integer, you are adding 1 to the "First" integer each iteration of the loop and overflowing the Total integer

```
1 run = 5000 + 0
2 run = 5000 + 5000 + 250
...
10000 run 12,548,750,000
```

The integer can't hold that and overflows.

The limit of a int64 is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. This would work for your code